# Express and Handlebars: Implementing multiple Defaultlayouts

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

i need two defaultlayout for my project nodejs (point of sale), the first: for the authentication page and the registration of a new user (cashier) (with his own CSS code), the second for the dashboard (pos interface as well as the product addition page ...) (with its own CSS code too).

the structure of my code should be:

```
views/
   layouts/
    mainDashboard.hbs
    mainLogin.hbs
   dashboard.hbs
   addProduct.hbs
   login.hbs
   register.hbs
```

My code in server.js (make juste one DefaultLayout):

```
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const app = new express();

// view enginge
app.engine(
  "handlebars",
  exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "mainlogin" ,
  })
);
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
```

Now i want to make two different layout with different CSS Code,
I find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866926/express-and-handlebars-implementing-multiple-themes/59238544#59238544) but I do not understand the solution (I specify that I am a beginner in node.js and that site is my first project So I need more detail please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain what is happening in the post you need to know some basic things:

1) [`res.render`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) is a express function which is used to render views(like .hbs, .ejs etc etc). Typically how you use render function is like this:

```
res.render('index.hbs')
```

Which returns some html and writes it to browser.

2) `app.use` is used to add middlewares(which is nothing but functions with 3 params) to the middleware chain.

```
app.use(middleware1);
app.use(middleware2);
```

For the above example every http request will go through middleware1 THEN middleware2 THEN the handler like `app.get` or `app.post`.

So basically a middleware is created to overwrite the `res.render` function

---

Now, to use the code shown there,

Make two folders inside views for two themes. For example,

```
views/
   theme1/
       index.hbs
   theme2/
       index.hbs
```

In the `index.js` file it should be normal express code then add the middlwares:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

...
...
...

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // cache original render
  var _render = res.render;

  res.render = function(view, options, done) {
    // custom logic to determine which theme to render
    var theme = getThemeFromRequest(req);
    // ends up rendering /themes/theme1/index.hbs
    _render.call(this, 'themes/' + theme + '/' + view, options, done);
  };
  next();
});

function getThemeFromRequest(req) {
  // in your case you probably would get this from req.hostname or something
  // but this example will render the file from theme2 if you add ?theme=2 to the url
  if(req.query && req.query.theme) {
    return 'theme' + req.query.theme;
  }
  // default to theme1
  return 'theme1';
}
app.listen(8080, ()=>console.log("Started"));
```

Now let's say you make a route:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('index.hbs');
});
```

Now go to, `http://localhost:8080/` it will render the `theme1/index.hbs` if you do `http://localhost:8080/?theme=theme2` it will render the `theme2/index.hbs`.

Hope you understood the explanation.

Comment: thanks for your response, i understand it but i had an error when i make my test i answer it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251312/use-multiples-defaultlayout-express-handlebars-in-nodejs-error-enoent-no)

Comment: Please accept the answer for this question if it solved your problem (the gray tick mark at the left of the answer)

Comment: yes i did it when my probleme solved. follow this link for complete code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251312/use-multiples-defaultlayout-express-handlebars-in-nodejs-error-enoent-no/59251904#59251904)