# Use multiples DefaultLayout (express-handlebars) in Nodejs: ( Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory )

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I ask my probleme [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246280/express-and-handlebars-implementing-multiple-defaultlayouts)

But after I use the proposed solution I had this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\test\views\layouts\index.handlebars'
structur of my code
```

structure of my code:

```
views/
 themes
  theme1
   layouts/
    index.hbs
   content1.hbs
  theme2
   layouts/
    index.hbs
   content2.hbs
index.js
```

in index.js i use this code : i add folder layouts in this line of code:

```
_render.call(this, 'themes/' + theme + '/layouts/' + view, options, done);
```

All code (index.js):

```
 const express = require("express");
    const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
    const app = express();




    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      // cache original render
      var _render = res.render;

      res.render = function(view, options, done) {
        // custom logic to determine which theme to render
        var theme = getThemeFromRequest(req);
        // ends up rendering /themes/theme1/index.hbs
        _render.call(this, 'themes/' + theme + '/layouts/' + view, options, done);
      };
      next();
    });

    function getThemeFromRequest(req) {
      // in your case you probably would get this from req.hostname or something
      // but this example will render the file from theme2 if you add ?theme=2 to the url
      if(req.query && req.query.theme) {
        return 'theme' + req.query.theme;
      }
      // default to theme1
      return 'theme1';
    }

    // view enginge
    app.engine(
      "hbs",
      exphbs({
        defaultLayout: "index" ,
      })
);
app.set("view engine", "hbs");


app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('index.hbs');
});

app.listen(8080, ()=>console.log("Started"));
```

thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to `express-handlebars`'s default path resolving. Add `layout: false` to disable it.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('index.hbs', {layout: false});
});
```

Or `defaultLayout: null`

```
app.engine(
      "hbs",
      exphbs({
        defaultLayout: null ,
      })
```

Comment: thank you very much, its worked :) , but we need to change this line of code  `return "theme"+ req.query.theme; ` with  `return "/" + req.query.theme; `